# Why can I not use the output of my function to get an output for my other defined function in R?

Tags: r

For my class, I am trying to create a function that gives my output as a reduced fraction of x and y from my function called GCD, which finds the greatest common divisor

Let's let `x <- 85` and `y <- 5` for simplicity

```
GCD(85,5)
[1] 5

simplify_rat <- function(85,5) {
GCD(x,y)
gcd <- c(GCD(x,y))
  n <- (y/gcd)
  d <- (x/gcd)
  print(cat(n, "/", d, "\n"))
  }
```

But I get this output with no reduced fraction

```
[1] 5
[1] 5
/  
NULL
```

Why am I not able to use the output from GCD? Is there a way to make this usable?

Comment: This is not valid R code. `function(85, 5)` will produce an error. Also: Always explicitly state where any non-base-R packages are coming from. Is `GCD` from `DescTools`?

Comment: @Murhp says "my function called GCD"

Comment: @djbetancourt Where is the *code* for his function `GCD`? This is not a reproducible example.

Comment: I don't know @Maurits Evers, that might be the good question to ask to @Murhp. I agree that this is not a reproducible example, @Murhp should provide the code of `GCD`. However, @Edward managed to provide an answer just by knowing that `GCD` "finds the greatest common divisor".

Comment: It was a rhetorical question @djbetancourt. These kind of questions (without reproducible code and a clear problem statement) have very little merit to Stack Overflow. The point was to encourage OP to edit his post according to SO posting guidelines. Answers to such questions are then often based on speculations and may not actually address the issue at hand. The issue seems to have nothing to do with what `GCD` does or is. The issue is with wrong R syntax when declaring a custom function.

Comment: Have you seen the paragraph you wrote for such a minuscule matter? (is also rhetorical, of course you saw). The problem is when we humans start acting as robots and put strict rules above common sense and practicity. Your first comment was more showing that you missed some information provided by the OP, which I just made you aware of. I agree, the issue has nothing to do with `GCD`... and who is saying `GCD` was the issue? Not even the question itself.

Comment: What are you on about @djbetancourt? You are obviously still fairly new to Stack Overflow, and I'm trying to explain to OP (and you) what constitutes a good question. We do this multiple times a day, and it is through those efforts that SO maintains a record of high-quality questions & answers. This question is not one of them. Obviously you are free to post superfluous comments and criticise Stack Overflow's "strict rules" (which are very much in-line with "common sense"). A better way forward for you would be to become more knowledgable with SO's posting guidelines!

Comment: Is that really what you are trying to do? Not quite evident to me. It is not SO what I'm criticizing, is how you @Mauritius Evers approaches the issues in a question made by someone even newer than me to SO. In the few minutes that I've been member of SO, I've seen many people explicitly and accurately indicate the OP what is wrong with its question and provide a link to "how do I ask a good question". Your comment was not doing one or the other. Also, if I cared about it, I would say "superflows" is a rude word to refer to the comments of other SO members. Please read some guidelines on that.

Answer (score 2):

Always pass variable parameters to your functions:

```
require(DescTools)

simplify_rat <- function(x,y) {
  gcd <- c(GCD(x,y))
  n <- (y/gcd)
  d <- (x/gcd)
  cat(n, "/", d, "\n")
}

simplify_rat(85,5)
```

---

```
1 / 17
```